# symfony patten regex trick

Tags: php, regex, symfony

I have my firewall on symfony, and I want it to work on all the site except a specific folder.

something like this:

```
  members_secured_area:
                pattern: ^/
                provider: entity_searchers
                anonymous: ~
                form_login:
                    check_path: /searchers/login_check
                    login_path: /searchers/login
                    default_target_path: /searchers/
                logout:
                    path:   /searchers/logout
                    target: /searchers/login
```

but I want this not to infulence the --> site.com/crm
I understand the the patter is regex but could not solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not very experienced with Symfony nor its firewall, but regex-wise this should work provided the regex engine supports [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
pattern: ^/(?!crm)
```

http://regexr.com?35efu

Comment: where were you in the last 8 hours I wasted! fits perfectly to my solution

Comment: Heheh I was sleeping then just had a dentist appointment actually, you're welcome. `=]`

Comment: hh one more thingdo you know how to do not crm and not foo for example:  ^/(?!crm AND ?!foo)

Comment: You mean to not affect 2 folders? Yeah try `^/(?!crm|foo)` the pipe means OR in regex, so it matches the `/` at start of string which is not followed by `crm` nor `foo`. `=]`